# JsonSchema is not validated with oneOf

Tags: jsonschema, tv4

Need help to find the bug with this schema. It has oneOf operator. 
Schema is here :

```
   `{
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "type",
        "body"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "type": {
            "description": "type of the document to post",
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
                "123",
                "456"                    
            ]
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "body",
            "oneOf": [{
                "$ref": "#/definitions/abc",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/def"
            }]
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "abc": {                
            "type": "array",
            "description": "abc",
           "properties" : {
               "name" : { "type" : "string"  }
         }
        },
        "def": {                
            "type": "array",
            "description": "users","properties" : {
               "name" : { "type" : "string"  }
         }
        }
    }
}`
```

My Json is this :

```
  `{
            "type": "123",
            "body": {
                "abc": [{
                    "name": "test"
                }]
            }
        }`
```

It does not validate with tv4 and I also tried this  [online tool](http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/). It works without oneOf operator. Otherwise it does not validate it any tool.

**Edit** :

After reading the answers I modified the schema. New schema is :

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "type": {
        "description": "type of the document to post",
        "type": "string",

    },
    "body": {
        "type": "object",
        "description": "body",
        "properties": {
            "customers": {
                "type": "array"
            }
        },
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "title": "customers prop",
                "properties": { 
                    "customers": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "description": "customers",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

And json is here

```
{
"type": "customer",
"body": {
    "none": [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it validates. I want to enforce one of "customers" or "users" in the body. To test I have removed users from the body.

Pl help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have the type at root level, you probably want the oneOf statement to check that an object with type "customer" has customers in the body (even though I would suggest skipping the body and placing customers and users directly in root object).

This works with your example, will require that an object with type "customer" has a body with "customers", and to clarify the matching, I let customer have the property "name" while the user has "username":

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "type": { "type": "string" },
    "body": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "customers": { 
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/customer" }
        },
        "users": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/user" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "customer": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "name": { "type": "string" } },
      "required": [ "name" ]
    },
    "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": { "username": { "type": "string" } },
      "required": [ "username" ]
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "pattern": "customer"
        },
        "body": {
          "required": [ "customers" ]
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "pattern": "user"
        },
        "body": {
          "required": [ "users" ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the data is passing both of your sub-schemas.  `oneOf` means "match *exactly* one" - if you want "match *at least* one", then use `anyOf`.

In fact, both of your sub-schemas will pass *all data*.  The reason is that `properties` is ignored when dealing with arrays.

What you presumably wanted to do instead is specify properties for the *items* in the array.  For this, you need the `items` keyword:

```
"definitions": {
    "abc": {                
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties" : {
                "name" : { "type" : "string"  }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(You'll also need to add some distinct constraints - at the moment, both the `"abc"` and `"def"` definitions are identical apart from `description`, which makes the `oneOf` impossible because it will always match both or neither.)

Answer (score 1):

When using `"type": "array"` then the item type is defined in the `"items"` property not `"properties"` property... Also both types in `oneOf` are same, but only one must match.

Try

```
      ...
      "definitions": {
        "abc": {                
            "type": "array",
            "description": "abc",
           "items" : {
               "name" : { "type" : "string"  }
         }
        },
        "def": {                
            "type": "array",
            "description": "users",
            "items" : {
               "username" : { "type" : "string"  }
            }
        }
    }
```